# Converting each to a + bi form

Tags: complex-numbers

So i was given Two questions and solved one which I was wondering if i'm correct and the second question i'm completely lost on it.

A) $$\frac{1+i}{2-3i} - \frac{1-i}{-2+3i}=\\
\frac{(1+i)(2+3i)}{(2-3i)(2+3i)}+\frac{(1-i)(-2-3i)}{(-2+3i)(-2-3i)}=\\
\frac{-1+5i}{13i}+\frac{-5-i}{13i}=\\
=\frac{-6+4i}{13i}$$

And the second question which I'm completely lost on is

B) $\left(\frac{3\sqrt 3-i}{1-i}\right)$ $+$ $\left(\frac{\sqrt 3+7i}{\sqrt 3 - i}\right)$

I feel as if it follows the above question, but i'm unsure if the top is correct. If so how would i deal with the square root?

Comment: Where is the matrix?

Comment: I edited the first two lines of the first expression. I don't know what the third expression is supposed to mean (where to the parentheses belong to?). Please, look at my edit and finish the first expression. If you do not do that, we cannot help yo since we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Your edit is correct

Comment: I can't help but comment that $2 - 3i = -(-2 + 3i)$ so finding a common denominator doesn't have to be so arduous.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is multiplication by the conjugate. So,
\begin{align}
\frac{1+i}{2-3i}-\frac{1-i}{-2+3i}&=\frac{(1+i)}{(2-3i)}\frac{(2+3i)}{(2+3i)}-\frac{(1-i)}{(-2+3i)}\frac{(-2-3i)}{(-2-3i)}\\
&=\frac{2+3i+2i+(3i^2)}{4+6i-6i-(3i)^2}-\frac{-2-3i+2i+(3i^2)}{4+6i-6i-(3i)^2}\\
&=\frac{-1+5i}{13}-\frac{-5-i}{13} \ \text{since} \ (3i)^2=-9\\
&=\frac{-1+5i+5+i}{13}\\
&=\frac{4}{13}+\frac{6}{13}i.
\end{align}
For the second question you have, you can follow the same method.

**Note:** In general, if one has a quotient of the form
$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}$$
then to make matters more simple, you want to get rid of the '$i$' in the denominator. To do this, you multiply by the complex conjugate of the number in the denominate (remember if $z=a+bi$ then its conjugate has the form $\bar{z}=a-bi$). Therefore, a simpler form is
$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\cdot\frac{a+bi}{c-di}.$$
If you complete the algebra you will notice that the result is far simpler.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you for the explanation